# Slash Command Registering not working properly

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

my discord bot has an error. A few days ago, it would say at startup 'Registering 21 slash commands..' 'Succesfully loaded 21 slash commands..'. It now says 'Registering 0' and 'Loaded 0'. Also, i adjusted the code of deploy-commands.js, so it would have global commands instead of guild-only commands. It worked fine until today, and i'm not getting any kind of errors in the console. I'll share my deploy-commands.js with you guys, i hope an answer is found.

*Note: In the deploy-commands.js is a piece of code which activates index.js, as the host cant execute a command after doing index.js.*

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('path');

const commands = [];

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.js');

try {
  const indexCommand = require(indexPath);
  commands.push(indexCommand.data.toJSON());
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Reloading ${commands.length} commands started.`);

    const data = await rest.put(
      Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
      { body: commands },
    );

    console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Thanks!

I already tried to ask a couple friends of mine, but they didn't see any error. I looked at the code multiple times but also couldn't find any faults.

Comment: can you please share `index.js` file and a screenshot of `commands` directory